# what does it mean by "f: U x I -> S"

Tags: collaborative-filtering

what does it mean by "f: U x I -> S"? My material says this function predicts rating of a user u for a new item i. But what is "x" there? Anyone please explain the symbols for me..

The material I used: Recommender system handbook - Ricci

"In order to give a formal definition of the item recommendation task, we need to introduce some notation. Thus, the set of users in the system will be denoted by U,and the set of items by I. Moreover, we denote by R the set of ratings recorded in the system, and write S the set of possible values for a rating...

Two of the most important problems associated with recommender systems are the best item and top-N recommendation problems. The first problem consists in finding, for a particular user u, the new item i ∈ I \ Iu for which u is most likely to be interested in. When ratings are available, this task is most often defined as a regression or (multi-class) classification problem where the goal is to learn a function ***f : U ×I →S*** that predicts the rating f (u, i) of a user u for a new item i..."

Comment: What material are you referring to?  There are multiple methods to calculate collaborative-filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the symbol for [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Comment: Of course it's the symbol for Cartesian product. However, in this case, the function which predicts rating of a user u for a new item i can't be as simple as Cartesian product. Why using "x"?

Comment: Well, f: U x I -> S just means that the function f is defined on the set of the couples (u, i) with u \in U and i \in I, and that the codomain of f is the set S. It does not specify *how* the function is defined, just its domain and codomain.

Comment: So there's such kind of notation. Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer if you think that it answers your question. :)